# How to print only the first sentence in string [C]?

Tags: c, string, input, printing, strstr

Example:

```
void stringEvaluation(char *name){
    if (strstr(name, "Tall") != NULL)
        --here I would like to print only "John Doe"--

}

int main{
    char name[160 + 1];
    scanf("%[^\n]%*c", name);

    stringEvaluation(name);

return 0;
}
```

and this is the input

"John Doe (45). Black. Tall. Brown eyes"

Comment: What do you want as the output? "John Doe (45)."? If that's the case you can loop through the input string letter by letter and keep printing them and once you encounter a '.' , break the loop.

Comment: Or you could simply use strtok.

Answer (score 1):

Your request is unclear. For example, do as follows.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>

void stringEvaluation(const char *s){
    const char *p;

    if(s == NULL || *s == '\0'){
        puts("invalid format.");
        return ;
    }
    (p = strchr(s, '(')) || (p = strchr(s, '.'));
    if(p == NULL){
        puts("invalid format.");
        return ;
    }
    //find end
    while(!isalpha((unsigned char)p[-1]))
        --p;
    while(s < p)
        putchar(*s++);
}

int main(void){
    char name[160 + 1] = "";
    scanf("%160[^\n]%*c", name);

    stringEvaluation(name);

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I am using strtok() to get the name. Please note, this will work only if you have "()" in your string.

```
void stringEvaluation(char *name){
    if (strstr(name, "Tall") != NULL)
    {
        char *nameEnd = strtok(name, "("); //Returns address of '('
        if(NULL != nameEnd)
        {
            int nameLength = nameEnd - name - 1; // 1 for space after name.

            char *onlyName = malloc((nameLength + 1) * sizeof(char)); // 1 for terminating '\0'
            if(NULL != onlyName)
            {
                //Copy name part.
                strncpy(onlyName, name, nameLength);
                onlyName[nameLength] = '\0'; //Make onlyName a string

                printf("Name: [%s]\n", onlyName);

                free(onlyName);
                onlyName = NULL;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have assumed that name will be at first place in your input string. Then following small logic will work for you.

```
void stringEvaluation(char *name){
    char *p;
    char OutPut[50]={0};
    if (strstr(name, "Tall") != NULL)
    {
        p = strstr(name," ");
        p++;
        p = strstr(p," ");
        strncpy(OutPut,name,(p-name));
        printf("name=%s\n",OutPut);
    }

}
```